# Parsing JSON file inside the database using Java

Tags: java, json

I want to put all of the json fields with their each values inside the database,

The ERROR is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/Json

Example JSON I want to put inside my database,

```
[{
"name": "Canada",
"topLevelDomain": [".ca"],
"alpha2Code": "CA",
"callingCodes": ["1"]
}]
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.json.*;

public boolean addToDatabase(String fileName) {
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Country ( name ,
     topLevelDomain, alpha2Code , callingCodes) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? );");
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader(new File (fileName)));
    JsonArray array = reader.readArray();
    for (JsonValue jv : array ) {
        JsonObject jo = array.getJsonObject(jv);
        String n = jo.getString("name");
        ps.setString(1, n);
        String t = jo.getString("topLevelDomain");
        ps.setString(2, t);
        String a = jo.getString("alpha2Code");
        ps.setString(3, a);
        String c = jo.getString("callingCodes");
        ps.setString(4, c);
        ps.executeUpdate();                     
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return(false);
}
return(true);
```

}

Comment: You miss the `javax.json-api.jar` in your classpath

Comment: @Jens i have the javax path

Comment: what means *you have the javax path*?

Comment: @Jens its the jar for the json, and i have a database while running it,
how can i run sqlite together with the json?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing `NoClassDefFoundError` for any class that means the corresponding jar which contains the particular class has not loaded in the classpath.

You have missed the `javax.json-api` jar in the classpath. Add the jar and execute it.

**Reference :** [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420167/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-json-json)